# Eclipse Web Service - No response when passing Parameters

Tags: eclipse

I created a **WEB SERVICE** in Eclipse Helios that simply returns the value that I pass to it.

When I write a function without parameters and run in the server, the "Status" field shows 999 in the Web Service Explorer.

```
package com.dyn.amic;

public class DoSomething {

    public int Something(){

        return 999;
}

}
```

But when I pass a parameter and run it again, the "Status" field is blank.

```
package com.dyn.amic;

public class DoSomething {

public int Something(int num){

    return num;

    }
}
```

The console is not showing any error or exception. But It shows IOException when I invoke it without passing any number.

Please give your suggestions... I am struggling with this the whole day!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine now. Forgot to add the web service and web method annotations in my java dynamic project (@WebService and @WebMethod)!! My bad.

```
1) Created Java file with classes and functions
2) Added @WebService above the class
3) Added @WebMethod above the method
4) Right Click on the java file --> Webservice --> Create Web Service --> Select the appropriate Apache Axis, select Monitor the web service and finish
```